# How can I add and show a new select value to a jquery combo box autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery UI autocomplete combobox which is populated with a select box.

Here is the code:

```
$.widget( "ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
        var input,
            self = this,
            select = this.element.hide(),
            selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
            wrapper = this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                .addClass( "ui-combobox" )
                .insertAfter( select );

        input = $( "<input>" )
            .appendTo( wrapper )
            .val( value )
            .addClass( "ui-state-default ui-combobox-input" )
            .autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 0,
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                    response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                        var text = $( this ).text();
                        if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                            return {
                                label: text.replace(
                                    new RegExp(
                                        "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                        $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                        ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                    ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                value: text,
                                option: this
                            };
                    }) );
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option
                    });
                },
                change: function( event, ui ) {
                    if ( !ui.item ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                            valid = false;
                        select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                            if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                this.selected = valid = true;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if ( !valid ) {
                            // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                            $( this ).val( "" );
                            select.val( "" );
                            input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

        input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };

        $( "<a>" )
            .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
            .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
            .appendTo( wrapper )
            .button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                },
                text: false
            })
            .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
            .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle" )
            .click(function() {
                // close if already visible
                if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                    input.autocomplete( "close" );
                    return;
                }

                // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                $( this ).blur();

                // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                input.focus();
            });
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
    }
});
```

Here is a screenshot showing the form:
[image]

When a user clicks 'add Author' a modal loads for them to create a new Author model object. I want to add and show the newly created author in the jquery UI combobox. 
I'm using Rails 3.2 and use a create.js.erb file to control the response from creating the object.

Comment: Do you have to use the underlying `select`? This might be easier if you could dynamically add/remove items to an array instead of updating a `select` element.

Comment: ok that sounds interesting. In the case that I use an array how can I show that a newly added item is the one to show in the search box? Also I was using the select because it stores the data for the element I submit with the form. That way when the form is submitted the id of the author is sent along with the form parameters.